# In ADS, how do I vary capacitance values of a capacitor in my circuit and plot the transfer?

Tags: ads

I want to see how the transfer function behaves as the value of a capacitor changes.

I've currently set up some s-parameters and a parameter sweep, but I'm not quite sure how to get it to work. Am I on the right track? Are s-parameters the right technique?

Comment: To measure what's usually called a transfer function, you probably want to do an AC simulation rather than S-parameter simulation. If you share your actual circuit, and how you define the transfer function (what is input and what is output), it would be easier to give a definitive answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton Why would the AC simulation be preferred? I think I may be using the terminology incorrectly. Basically I'd like a plot of the capacitance vs. magnitude of output/input (transfer function?)

Comment: @ThePhoton I'd like the input/output for all the terminals. It's a very simple transmission line with two ports, so a schematic wouldn't give any info. I'd like output/input, and reflected voltage/input. I'm just having trouble starting it since I'm new to ADS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you are looking for, you can either do AC or S parameter simulation. To visualize the effect of the capacitors value you can either use "tune" or a parameteric sweep.

To tune click on the tuning fork icon and click on the capacitor. Then you should see the simulation result and how it changes when you change the slide bar with the capacitors value.

The second option is to use the parameter sweep controller. In order to do that you need to declare a variable to hold the capacitors value (var icon). Set the variable with some initial value and then assign it to the capacitors value. It should be something like "C= MyC pF" note that the units are in pF's, you can obviously change that. 
After declaring the variable setup the parameteric sweep controller to sweep the variable (you will also need to point the controller to your main simulation controller)

I hope this is clear enough, I typed this from my phone. If it's not clear enough say so in the comments and I'll edit the answer from the pc with screen shots.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give it a try tomorrow and let you know if I have any questions

Comment: Do you know how I can get a plot of the transfer vs. capacitance?

Comment: When plotting you can click on Plot vs and choose your capacitance variable